# Change Artifactory url

Tags: docker, artifactory, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm running `Artifactory OSS 7.3.2` in a `Docker` container on `Ubuntu 18.04`

I can access the gui using http://myhost:8082.

But I'd like to use such an url: http://myhost/myartifactory/.

I'm using a nginx proxy.  But I don't find how to do that.

I tried with something basic like

```
set $artifactory_upstream artifactory:8082;
location /test/ {
    proxy_pass http://$artifactory_upstream/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
}
```

But it seems artifactory is always redirecting to http://myhost/ui.

Is there a way to customize the url ?